Find $\bigcup_{i\in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{R} \times [i,i+1]$
$$\bigcup_{i\in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{R} \times [i,i+1]$$
Intutively, it follows that
$$\bigcup_{i\in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{R} \times [i,i+1]=  \{(x,y) : x \in \mathbb{R} , y \in [1,\infty)\}
$$
We wish to show that $$\bigcup_{i\in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{R} \times [i,i+1] \subseteq \{(x,y) : x \in \mathbb{R}, y\in [1,\infty)\}$$ and vice versa
To do so we first prove that
$$\mathbb{R} \times \bigcup_{i\in \mathbb{N}}[i,i+1]=\bigcup_{i\in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{R} \times [i,i+1]  $$
We proceed inductively
We first prove $$\mathbb{R} \times \bigcup_{i=1}[i,i+1]= \bigcup_{i=1} \mathbb{R} \times [i,i+1]$$
This is trivially true
We now assume $$\mathbb{R} \times \bigcup_{1\leq i\leq n}[i,i+1]=\bigcup_{1\leq i\leq n } \mathbb{R} \times [i,i+1]  $$
We now wish to prove that $$\mathbb{R} \times \bigcup_{1 \leq i \leq n+1} [i,i+1] = \bigcup_{1 \leq i \leq n+1} \mathbb{R} \times [i,i+1]$$
We now let $$ \bigcup_{1\leq i\leq n}[i,i+1]=A$$
We thus have $$\mathbb{R} \times (A \cup [i,i+1])= (\mathbb{R} \times A) \cup (\mathbb{R} \times [n,n+1]) $$
We then have $$\bigcup_{1\leq i \leq n} \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \times [i,i+1] \cup \bigcup_{i=n+1}[n+1,n+2] $$
Not sure what to do from here

What would it mean to "find" such a thing?  Are you asking:  "identify another, more familiar set, which is naturally bijective with this one"?  Something else?

For instance, consider the set $S={(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2,|,y≥1}$.  That's pretty familiar...and any point in that set can be identified with a point in your set, and conversely.  Is that the sort of thing you meant?

@lulu yes, that's what I mean

I suggest editing to clarify that point.  Regardless, I suggest trying to argue that my half-plane $S$ fits the bill.

It is quite trivial once you get the knack of these kind of proofs. Let $A=\bigcup_{i\in \mathbb{N}}\mathbb{R}\times [i,i+1]$ and $B=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2: y\geq 1\}$.
If $(a,b)\in A$, then $\exists i\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $(a,b)\in \mathbb{R}\times [i,i+1]$, then $a\in \mathbb{R}$ and $b\in [i,i+1]$, then $b\geq i$, thus $b\geq 1$, then $(a,b)\in B$.
If $(a,b)\in B$, then $a\in \mathbb{R}$ and $b\geq 1$. Since $\{[i,i+1)\}_{i\in \mathbb{N}}$ is a partition of $[1,\infty)$, then there exists some $i\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $b\in [i,i+1)\subset [i,i+1]$, thus $(a,b)\in \mathbb{R}\times [i,i+1]\subset A$.
